# Java Compiler Error?

Tags: java

Here's the error I keep getting when trying to run my new method I'm creating.

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExceptio... Coordinate out of bounds! 
at sun.awt.image.ByteInterleavedRaster.getD... Source) 
at java.awt.image.BufferedImage.getRGB(Unkn... Source) 
at SimplePicture.getBasicPixel(SimplePictur... 
at Pixel.getColor(Pixel.java:184) 
at Picture.rotate(Picture.java:253)`
```

Here's the code-

```
public Picture rotate () { 
    Picture newPic = new Picture(getWidth(),getHeight()); 
    for (int x=0;x<getWidth();x++)  
        for (int y=0;y<getHeight()*2;y++) { 
            Pixel a = getPixel (x,y); 
            Pixel c = getPixel (getWidth()-1-x,y); 
            a.setColor (c.getColor()); 
            c.setColor (a.getColor());
        } 
    return newPic; 
}
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: There is no compiler error in evidence here, just a runtime exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try not to multiply the height by 2?

```
for (int y=0;y<getHeight()*2;y++){
```

According to the error message, your coordinates gets out of wack. Ill assume this is because your loop has twice the amount of pixels/iterations as the height - and then ruńs way to many times.